# Child Of does not obey instancing

Tags: instances

I want to have identical instances of an object in three parent objects -- my case is to have the same lamp covers along four circle paths (converted to mesh) that has "Property >> Instancing >> Vertices" enabled.

If I use the Child_Of constraint, instancing is ignored on these path meshes.

I suppose I could instead have four linked-duplicate children, each individually parented to the circle path parent mesh, but was wondering if a cleaner alternative existed.

Comment: Hello, could you please show a drawing of your final goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry node is the way to go. You can instance an object on the vertices with a simple setup like this one. Then put the geometry node setup on the objects you want

[image]